# Further questions about from product $\sigma$-algebra to component ones

Tags: measure-theory

This is a continuation of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23009/1281) and inspired by [Arturo Margidin's reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/from-sigma-algebra-on-product-space-to-sigma-algebra-on-component-space/23017#23017).

Suppose there are a collection of measurable spaces $(X_i, \mathbb{S}_i), i \in I$. Let $\mathbf{X}=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, and let $\mathbb{S}=\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{S}_i$ be the product $\sigma$-algebra.

1. Suppose $A_{i_0}\subseteq X_{i_0}$ is such that $A_{i_0}\times\prod_{j\neq i_0}X_j\in\mathbb{S}$. Does it follow that $A_{i_0}\in\mathbb{S}_{i_0}$?
2. More generally, suppose we have a family of subsets, $A_i\subseteq X_i$, and we know that $A_j\in\mathbb{S}_j$ for all $j\neq i_0$ and that $\prod_{i\in I}A_i\in\mathbb{S}$. Does it follow that $A_{i_0}\in \mathbb{S}_{i_0}$?
3. Basically, I would like to reconstruct each $\mathbb{S}_i$
   from $\prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{S}_i$.
   If you have other approaches, please
   don't hesitate to reply. In particular, Part 1 and Part 2 are attempts based on projection of measurable rectangles in the product $\sigma$-algebra. I was wondering if it is possible to go from sectioning a measurable set in the product $\sigma$-algebra?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is your index set $I$ finite, countably many, or arbitrary?

Comment: @Tim: I think your use of quantifiers was obscuring, rather than clarifying, your questions 1 and 2; in 1, it seemed at first as if you were selecting $A_i$ for all $X_i$ and asking about all of them simultaneously. I've reworded them, hopefully to make them clearer.

Comment: @Morning: $I$ is arbitrary. But if your treatment is different for different cardinality of $I$, I also would like to hear.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks! In my original wording, for example for Part 1, I intended to say $i_0$ as used in your wording is arbitrary in $I$.

Comment: @Tim: This is immediate from the phrasing.

Comment: @Tim, @Morning: You can restrict to countable index set, because in the uncountable case, any element of $\mathbb{S}$ must be of the form $B\times\prod_{i\notin I_0}X_i$ where $B\subseteq \prod_{i\in I_0}X_i$ and $I_0\subseteq I$ is countable. (These sets form a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the product $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks. I posted an answer. Please check and let me know if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $I$ to be countable as suggested by Arturo Magidin. We show part (2). Define
$$
{\cal G} = \{\pi_i^{-1}(A):A\in \mathbb S_i, i\in I\}.
$$
The product $\sigma$-field $\mathbb S$ is generated by $\cal G$. Fix $i_0$, and pick arbitrary $x_i\in A_i$ for every $i\in I, i\neq i_0$. (Note that one needs to assume $\mathbb S_i\ni A_i\neq \emptyset$, otherwise the statement is obviously not correct.)

Define a mapping 
$$
T_{i_0} : X_{i_0}\ni x_{i_0} \mapsto \{x_i\}_{t\in I}\in {\bf X}.
$$
Observe that if $T_{i_0}$ is $\mathbb S_{i_0}/\mathbb S$ measurable, then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i\in\mathbb S$ implies that $T_{i_0}^{-1}(\prod_{i\in I}A_i) = A_{i_0}\in\mathbb S_{i_0}$, and we are done.

It remains to show that $T_{i_0}$ is measurable and it suffices to show that $T_{i_0}^{-1}(G)\in\mathbb S_{i_0}$ for all $G\in \cal G$. This is true since for all $i\in I, A\in \mathbb S_i$, $T_{i_0}^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(A))$ equals (1) $A$ if $i=i_0$, (2) $X_{i_0}$ if $i\neq i_0, x_i\in A$, and (3) $\emptyset$ if $i\neq i_0, x_i\notin A$.

Comment: it seems good, and if it is, then it answers (1) by taking $A_j = X_j$ with $j\neq i$.

Comment: @Arturo Right, (1) is a special case of (2). Thanks.